Absolute Scale and Distance Function in Hyperbolic Geometry
I have a question about intuition on key differences between axiomatic hyperbolic and Euklidean geometries. More precisely I'm pondering about last sentence of following explanations from wikipedia:

[...] Concepts that are equivalent in Euclidean geometry are not equivalent in hyperbolic geometry; new concepts need to be introduced. Further, because of the angle of parallelism, hyperbolic geometry has an absolute scale, a relation between distance and angle measurements.

Question: Could somebody elaborate in detail what in context of hyperbolic geometry an absolute scale is (... in contrast which not exists in Euklidean geometry) and how it provids relation between distance and angle measurements in paradigmatically totally different nature as in Euklidean geometry?
So far I understand it correctly the failure to have an absolute scale in Euklidean geometry comes just from the fact that to "measure distances" in EG we need to fix (for the whole "measuring process" we are going to concuct) a "scaling unit" which in EG comes always as a "noncanonical choice". In contrast the "angle" is an absolute quatity, ie "independent" of choosen scaling unit.
So in turn if we hypothetically could define distance in a geometry only in terms of angles (=absolue quantity), the distance function would also be "scale choice independent", so " canonical" or "absolute". And the difference between HG and EG is that in the former we can express distance as a function of involved angles, in EG obviuosly not (two distinct paralell lines could have arbitrary distance, but the angle between them is zero).
Firstly, is my attempt above to interpret the quoted statement on the concept of "absolute scale" correct? If not, could somebody clarify the meaning of the last quoted sentence from wikipedia site?

"Absolute scale" is not a math terminology. Keep in mind that anybody can edit a Wikipedia article.

Similar triangles will have the same angles but can have different lengths in Euclidean geometry. So say we have a right-triangle with legs of length $1$ and hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{2}$ will be similar to a right-triangle with legs of length $2$ and hypotenuse of length $2\sqrt{2}$. Note that in this case if I consider the ratios of lengths between the sides they're still $1$ or $\sqrt{2}$ for both triangles so it's not enough information to tell the two triangles are different.
However for hyperbolic triangles the angles force the sides to be a certain length so all similar triangles are congruent. If you compare the lengths of the sides those ratios will be different if the triangles are not similar. This means the ratios are sufficient to distinguish between two different hyperbolic triangles. It's that property that gives hyperbolic triangles absolute scale.

But what means the term "absolute scale" by definition? Or at least a reasonble definition?

@user267839 absolute scales are defined by a ratio that has has a fixed value. It allows you to describe objects without appealing to an arbitrary unit or measure. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_scale

yes, but ratio of what? Should this thought as a kind of "dividing unit out to make considered quantities unit independent"?

@user267839 here it's the length of the sides of the triangle or alternatively it's the area of the triangle with the sum of the angles. Basically the angles force the lengths to be exact unlike Euclidean triangles.

could you give an example calculation with a hyperbolic triangle (just to see where the significant differences in the calculation appear leading to this different bahaviour)? The example from the first paragraph in your answer demonstrates the failure of equivalence between "similarity" and "congluence" in Euklidean world. But I would like to see an explicit example from hyperbolic world making plausible why such failure cannot appear there.

maybe asking differently, in Euklidean geometry for a triangle the information ASA (angle, side, angle) determine completely the congluence type of a triangle. If in hyperbolic world congluence and similarity are the same, then for any triangle in hyperbolic setting there should be exist an explicit formula of a side length *depending only on it's angles", right? Is it possible to write it down explicitly?

@user267839 for a hyperbolic triangle AAA (angle, angle angle) is enough to determine the congruency type. You can find the construction of the side lengths using the hyperbolic law of cosines. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643900/how-to-compute-the-side-length-of-an-equilateral-hyperbolic-triangle-from-its-an

*congruence (typo)
